# Weblogic NodeManager Start Failure

Tags: weblogic

I've setup a weblogic cluster with 2 managed servers.In order to configure node manager on both nodes i've followed the related article :

http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/fmw/wls/12c/12_2_1/01-12-001-ConfiguringandUsingNodeManager/Configuring_and_Using_NM.html

with the following configuration :

Machine-0 :

```
 DomainsFile=/u01/app/oracle/config/domains/base_domain/Machine-
 0/nodemanager.domains
 LogLimit=0
 PropertiesVersion=12.1.3
 AuthenticationEnabled=true
 NodeManagerHome=/u01/app/oracle/config/domains/base_domain/Machine-0
 JavaHome=/opt/jdk1.8.0_131
 LogLevel=INFO
 DomainsFileEnabled=true
 StartScriptName=startWebLogic.sh
 ListenAddress=localhost
 NativeVersionEnabled=true
 ListenPort=5558
 LogToStderr=true
 SecureListener=false
 LogCount=1
 StopScriptEnabled=false
 QuitEnabled=false
 LogAppend=true
 StateCheckInterval=500
 CrashRecoveryEnabled=false
 StartScriptEnabled=true
 LogFile=/u01/app/oracle/config/domains/base_domain/Machine-
 0/nodemanager.log
 LogFormatter=weblogic.nodemanager.server.LogFormatter
 ListenBacklog=50
```

Machine-1 (the second managed server) has the same configuration with the exceptions of ports (5557) and name.
Although node manager is successfully started on both machines (startNodeManager.sh on machine-0 and machine-1) from admin console on Machine-0 the following error occurs and node manager doesnt start :

```
weblogic.nodemanager.NMConnectException
```

nodemanager.log of Machine-0 has no indications of errors or any helpful stuff.
Any help would be appreciated.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the things that I usually check when I am setting up a new WebLogic domain:

- It is possible that the Listen Address of `Machine-1` is not correct. Check the Listen Address of the machine from the WebLogic Domain Configuration. It should match the host's machine name. Using `localhost` might not work because the Admin Server is trying to connect to the `Machine-1`, which can be on the other server.
- Make sure to check if the port is reachable from the Admin Server's machine.
- Check that the Node Manager configuration uses Plain instead of SSL connection, as stated in your `nodemanager.properties` file. Under *Environments* > *Machines*, click the machine and go to Configuration Tab, Node Manager. Check if the Type is `Plain` and not `SSL`. Changing this will require a restart of the Admin Server.

Answer (score 0):

Please verify the items below before you start nodemanager.

1. Check if the nodemanager.domains has your domain name listed.
2. Try to see if the ports are listening using the commands below.

   ```
   netstat -an|grep 5557 
   netstat -an|grep 5558
   ```
3. Also, check if the nodemanager is reachable in weblogic console.